# Is a mapping torus of a solvmanifold always a solvmanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, geometric-topology

Is it true that the mapping torus of a solvmanifold is always a solvmanifold?

Some relevant facts, many from [Flat 3 manifolds and mapping tori of flat surfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423388/flat-3-manifolds-and-mapping-tori-of-flat-surfaces) :

- Every mapping torus of a compact nilmanifold is a (compact) solvmanifold see [Torus bundles and compact solvmanifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4379085/torus-bundles-and-compact-solvmanifolds)
- The 1d solvmanifolds are $ S^1, \mathbb{R} $. The mapping tori of $ S^1 $ are $ T^2,K^2 $ and the mapping tori of $ \mathbb{R} $ are $ \mathbb{R} \times S^1, M $ where $ M $ is the Mobius strip. These mapping tori are all solvmanifolds.
- The 2d solvmanifolds are $ \mathbb{R}^2, T^2,K^2,\mathbb{R} \times S^1, M $.
- The mapping tori of $ T^2 $ are given here [Bianchi classification of solvable Lie groups and cocompact subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317139/bianchi-classification-of-solvable-lie-groups-and-cocompact-subgroups) or here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414531/3-dimensional-solvmanifolds-and-thurston-geometries/416509#416509 in particular they are given by the trace of the mapping class and whether it is diagonalizable. Also they are all solvmanifolds since $ T^2 $ is a compact nilmanifold.
- The mapping tori of $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ are $ \mathbb{R}^2  \times S^1, \mathbb{R} \times M $. They are both solvmanifolds.
- The mapping tori of the cylinder $ S^1 \times M , \mathbb{R} \times T^2, \mathbb{R} \times K^2 , X $. The first three are solvmanifolds, unsure about the $ X $.
- The mapping tori of the Mobius strip $ M $ are $ S^1 \times M, Y $. The first is a solvmanifold, unsure about $ Y $.
- The four mapping tori of $ K^2 $ are given here [Mapping Torus of Klein bottle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373435/mapping-torus-of-klein-bottle) they are exactly the four flat compact nonorientable 3 manifolds. The trivial product $ S^1 \times K^2 $ is a solvmanifold. Unsure about the other three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be Q&A style because I figured out a counterexample while writing the question.

Every mapping torus of the Klein bottle admits a flat metric. So if every mapping torus of a solvmanifold were a solvmanifold then every mapping torus of the Klein bottle would be a flat solvmanifold. However that is not true. In the examples section of

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1997859?seq=1

all three dimensional flat solvmanifolds are listed. There are only seven. Five are the flat mapping tori (from the five finite order mapping classes) of $ T^2 $ and the two others are two of the mapping tori of the Klein bottle. Thus exactly two of the nontrivial mapping tori of the Klein bottle fail to be solvmanifolds